# Disable Carriage Return (Enter Key Press) in QPlainTextEdit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qplaintextedit

This is what my example looks like:

[image: Disable Return]

The text area is a `QPlainTextEdit()` object because I want the text to wrap to the second line. I think this is the best widget choice.

The user will only enter a maximum number of 90 characters in this box so I don't need a large text area.

I want to disable the key press Enter (carriage return). I got it to work but it seems hacky and I don't think it would work cross-platform (ex: Mac).

Surely, there's got to be a better way to prevent a carriage return key event in a `QPlainTextEdit` object?

**My Current Solution Explained**

Below, you can see I'm checking if an `IndexError` occurs because the `last_value` throws an `IndexError` when there's nothing in the QPlainTextEdit box. Then, I'm getting the last character and asking if it's equal to a new line. If it is, I'm re-setting the text without that new line and moving the cursor to the end.

```
    def some_event(self):
        try:
            last_value = self.field.toPlainText()[-1]
            if last_value == '\n':
                print('You Pressed Enter!', repr(last_value))
                self.field.setPlainText(self.field.toPlainText()[:-1])
                self.field.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        except IndexError:
            print('Index Error occurred')
            pass
```

**Full Code Minimal Working Example:**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QPushButton,
                             QApplication, QPlainTextEdit, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor

class BasicWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 400, 100)

        self.grid = QGridLayout()

        self.label = QLabel('Description Line 1')
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)

        self.field = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.field.setMaximumHeight(40)

        self.field.textChanged.connect(self.some_event)

        #TODO how to disable enter/return key events in this field?
        self.grid.addWidget(self.field, 1, 0)

        self.button = QPushButton('Some Button')
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

    def some_event(self):
        try:
            last_value = self.field.toPlainText()[-1]
            if last_value == '\n':
                print('You Pressed Enter!', repr(last_value))
                self.field.setPlainText(self.field.toPlainText()[:-1])
                self.field.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
        except IndexError:
            print('Index Error occurred')
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = BasicWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to override the [`keyPressEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) method of the [`QPlainTextEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html):

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QPushButton,
                             QApplication, QPlainTextEdit, QLabel)


class PlainTextEdit(QPlainTextEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter):
            return
        super().keyPressEvent(event)


class BasicWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 400, 100)
        self.label = QLabel("Description Line 1")
        self.field = PlainTextEdit()  
        self.field.setMaximumHeight(40)   
        self.button = QPushButton("Some Button")

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.field, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = BasicWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another option that implements the same logic is to use an [`eventFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter).

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QPushButton,
                             QApplication, QPlainTextEdit, QLabel)

class BasicWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 400, 100)
        self.label = QLabel("Description Line 1")
        self.field = QPlainTextEdit()  
        self.field.setMaximumHeight(40)   
        self.button = QPushButton("Some Button")

        self.field.installEventFilter(self)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.field, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.field and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter):
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = BasicWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @Jarad No, not for now, maybe in the future